# Is it possible to add different Headers and Footers for each Page via Google Docs Api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-docs

I am trying to add headers and footers to pages. I am using Google Doc API for it. I am able to add a default header and footer that appears on all the pages. But I want a different header and footer for each page.

The header request takes a `type` attribute, whose value could be DEFAULT or HEADER_FOOTER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED. The DEFAULT type looks ok and works fine. But it adds the header to all the pages. HEADER_FOOTER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED does not seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When creating the header via [CreateHeaderRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#CreateHeaderRequest) (or the footer via `CreateFooterRequest`), you can specify which section the header will apply to by providing a `sectionBreakLocation`. As you can see in the referenced documentation, when creating a header:

> The new header is applied to the `SectionStyle` at the location of the `SectionBreak` if specificed, otherwise it is applied to the DocumentStyle.

That is to say, the header you are creating is applying to all the document because you are not providing a section this header has to apply to. For that, you should provide the property `sectionBreakLocation`:

> The location of the `SectionBreak` which begins the section this header should belong to. If `sectionBreakLocation` is unset or if it refers to the first section break in the document body, the header applies to the `DocumentStyle`.

#### Reference:

- [CreateHeaderRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#CreateHeaderRequest)
- [Location](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#Location)

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try this out.
The type of Header should be `DEFAULT` only. Type is a mandatory field and looks like it takes only `DEFAULT` value.